# Check if skipws/noskipws flag is set for an input stream

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

In order to set the `std::skipws` (or `std::noskipws`) flag, one needs to write:

```
my_input_stream >> std::skipws; //or my_input_stream >> std::noskipws;
```

But how do I *check* if the flag is set? I need to enable `noskipws` for my `operator >>` , but I want to restore the previously set value after. I am aware of boost I/O state savers, but I need to do a demonstration for students and using boost might be overkill for this simple purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::ios_base::flags()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) :)

Comment: Ah, right. Now that you said it, it started to ring a bell. When I first started learning C++ many years ago, I remember I used to set any iostream flags like this. Later, I started using the standard manipulators and somehow forgot about this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [`flags()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) member function.  That will return the current flags, and you can test if the `std::ios_base::skipws` flag is set, like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::cin >> std::noskipws;
    if (!(std::cin.flags() & std::ios_base::skipws))
        std::cout << "no skipws set\n";
    std::cin >> std::skipws;
    if (std::cin.flags() & std::ios_base::skipws)
        std::cout << "skipws set";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the flags of your stream:

```
my_input_stream.flags() & std::ios_base::skipws
```